# margin: 0px auto VS margin: -50%

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm about to write some templates for a new little Project - and I just wondered about one thing:

If I want my whole page content to be inside a centered column, with - lets say - 800px width, the usual way of doing that would be this (at least, this is the way I always did it):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                text-align: center; /* IE6 */
            }

            #wrapper {
                margin: 0px auto;
                width: 800px;
                background-color: #eee; /* to see it better */
                text-align: left; /* IE6 */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            ... content ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, there is another method to do exactly the same thing, but with `margin: -50%;` (or a fixed value, in this case `margin: 400px;`), like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin-left: 50%;
            }

            #wrapper {
                margin-left: -400px;
                width: 800px;
                background-color: #eee; /* to see it better */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            ... content ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is - does one of this two methods have any advantages over the other? Or disadvantages? Is there a common 'best solution' for centering a main column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`margin:0 auto;` will make sure there are equal amounts of space on either side of the element.

`margin-left:50%;` is relative to the parent. For example, if the container is 1000px wide, you will have a left margin of 500px on the child element. However, that will not center the element, it will place it's left side in the middle — unless you hack it with a fixed value on the child element as in your example.

Usually, when you are dealing with a wrapper as in your case, `margin:0 auto;` is the simplest and most flexible solution. In other cases, you might find it better to use a percentage or fixed value (for example, when floating stuff).

Answer (score 2):

I only use the first method in this situation.

It's much more flexible because if I want to change the size of main div, or if I want to support other devices, there's a lot less changing needed.

The second method is a hack, and it's a hack that's not needed in modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are giving margin to the body of 50% to push the elements and again giving a negative margin to the wrapper to pull it in the previous place, this method works. But sometime browser doesn't render it properly.[see the question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169558/ie-7-negative-margin-error)

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that old IE versions probably would act differently with negative margin. Thanks for the information!